# Having trouble understanding recursion string

Tags: java, recursion

```
public void mystery7(String sWord){
    int nL=sWord.length();
    if (nL>=3) {
        mystery7(sWord.substring(0,nL/3));
        System.out.println(sWord.substring(0,nL/3));
        mystery7(sWord.substring(0,nL/3));
    }
}
```

I am having trouble with recursion. I have to find the input of mystery7("abcdefgjijkl") but I don't understand what happens when the first line in the "if" segment. If anyone can help, please do.

Comment: There is really no need to use Hungarian notation in Java...

Comment: Can you elaborate on what a mystery string is?

Answer (score 1):

The condition `if (nL>=3)` means that the recursive calls are only executed as long as the length of the input `String` is at least 3.

- The recursive method calls itself with the first third of the input String `sWord.substring(0,nL/3)`.
- Then it prints that first third of the String.
- Finally it calls itself again with the first third of the input String.

For the input "abcdefgjijkl", whose length is 12, mystery7("abcdefgjijkl") results in the following calls:

```
mystery7("abcdefgjijkl") 
    mystery7("abcd");
        mystery7("a"); // does nothing
        System.out.println("a");
        mystery7("a"); // does nothing
    System.out.println("abcd");
    mystery7("abcd");
        mystery7("a"); // does nothing
        System.out.println("a");
        mystery7("a"); // does nothing
```

Therefore the output is

```
a
abcd
a
```

Answer (score 0):

The first recursion function will execute recursively if the condition satisfies and once the recursion is over and while backtracking the `System.out.println(xxx)`  will come to play and the recursion kicks off again with that string.